# Simplest way to properly rotate MapView in Android?

Tags: android, rotation, android-mapview

I have an Android Activity that displays `Google Maps` through `MapView` control and extending `MapActivity`. When I progrmatically rotate the `MapView` using method `mapView.setRotation(some Integer)` instead of actual image rotation whole control rotates as shown in snapshot below. What is the simplest way to rotate map as done by default app of Google Maps.

I am using latest Map and Android APIs

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out MapsDemo examples in ANDROID_SDK\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google_inc_-7\samples\MapsDemo. It has rotation map demo!